# is there a Solution in jenkins to limit characters input for a TEXT parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have developed a parameterized Jenkins pipeline where i am using a TEXT parameter. I need a solution where TEXT parameter shouldn't allow more than 500 characters when users input during triggering the Job. It should flag when users exceed more than 500 characters.